# Xamarin issue "self.isModalInPresentation = false" not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, popover

I was trying to disable swiping effect on popover controller.My xamarin application running ios 13 getting some issue while swipping down the popover controller,So I need to disable default swipe effect on popover controller. In objective c and swift it has a property "isModelInPresentation" but in xamarin it is not available. Can any body help to disable swipe popover ?

Comment: navctlr.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[modalInPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-modalinpresentation?language=objc)** : A Boolean value indicating whether the view controller enforces a modal behavior.

> The default value of this property is **NO**. When you set it to **YES**, UIKit ignores events outside the view controller's bounds and prevents the interactive dismissal of the view controller while it is onscreen.

In Xamarin.iOS ,If setting `ModalInPresentation = True` , when swipping the viewController will not disappear . Else will disappear .

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    View = new UniversalView();

    base.ViewDidLoad();
    this.Title = "Second";
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    ModalInPresentation = true;
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have already tried with this.then i get the error " The name 'ModalInPresentation' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (WBid.WBidiPad.iOS)"

Comment: @Graycodder Okey , share your code where set this in Xamarin.iOS project .

Comment: I found the issue. Thank you for the support, i was Using xaamrin.ios old version .when i updated i can use ModelInPresentation .

Comment: @Graycodder Great! If answer be helpful , you can mark it  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ModalInPresentation = true;` in the `ViewDidLoad` of the presented page.

Or,

Use `YourPresentingPage.ModalInPresentation = true;` just before the code for presenting the page.